# Android recyclerview Animation not working with constraint layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I am applying recyclerview animation from this link 
[enter-animation-using-recyclerview-and-layoutanimation](https://proandroiddev.com/enter-animation-using-recyclerview-and-layoutanimation-part-1-list-75a874a5d213)

but the only change is my recyclerview is inside constraint layout where I need to set height as 0dp for relating views when I set heights as wrap_content or match_parent animation working good.

My XML code

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivBanner"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_img" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation_from_bottom"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ivBanner" />

 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

In recyclerview `android:layout_height="0dp"` I set as match_parent or wrap_content animation is working good so there is no issue with the `layout_animation_from_bottom`  Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue. I am able to use the same code and i do see the animation work smoothly. I don't think its a constriantlayout issue

Comment: but if I change my recyclerview height as wrap_content it is working only when recyclerview height is 0dp it is not working

Comment: in the github sample linked in the blogpost i changed wrap_content to 0dp for recyclerview and the animation works.

Comment: can you share GitHub link you found

Comment: https://github.com/patrick-iv/Enter-animation-demo. its also linked in the blog post. change to 0dp for recyclerview in list example and check yourself

Comment: But in this link, I didn't find any constraint layout my issue is only with constraint layout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167709/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-pitty).